# variance - covariance matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to write a function to calculate the variance - covariance matrix or second derivative matrix with respect to `v` of the following function, how can I do this in R? I can get the diagonal values but I do not know how to calculate the covariance values in R.

```
x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 10)
y = c(1.4, 3.5, 7.1, 8, 9)
v = list(a = .1, b= .5)
f = function(x, y, v) exp(v$a *x + v$b * y)
z = matrix(c(x, y), ncol=2)
var  = colSums(z^2 * f(x, y, v))
var
# [1] 31363.68 29849.59
```

Comment: Please expand your question by being more specific and show what you've tried.

Comment: Can you give a mathematical formula for your calculations?

Comment: Yes. For the covariance z[, 1] * z[, 2]  * f(x, y, v).

Comment: So you expect a single number from that equation? Are you having a problem typing that into R?

Comment: @ MrFlick: Yes. I do not know how to do it in R?